# Wrap a long line of text that is without spaces in visualforce rendered as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, html, pdf

Is there any CSS that can break a long line of text into multiple lines? I have the following table and I get the data from my org.

[image]

As you can see, the Detail column has text that overlaps with the next column. I have tried everything but in vain. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Did you tried CSS Display:inline-block ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `word-wrap` css property before to solve the long line issue. Check the below link out

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Let me know if it helps!